# save into another table

Tags: odoo

oI select same field from `mo.queue` and I want save it into the `procurement.order` table

My code looks as follows:

```
def action_ship_create(self, cr, uid, ids, id_queue, context=None):
    queue_obj = self.pool.get('mo.queue'). browse (cr, uid, id_queue, context=context)
    mo_name = queue_obj.name 
    query_param = (mo_name)
    cr.execute("select origin,create_date,product_uos_qty,product_qty,name,city from mo_queue",(query_param,))
    ads = cr.fetchone()
    name = ads and ads [0] or None
    print "======================"
    print name
    print "======================"

    val = { 'origin': name,
          } 
    print "======================"
    print val
    print "======================"  

    return {'value': val }  


    proc_id = self.pool.get('procurement.order').create(cr, uid, {
        'origin':origin,
    })
    proc_ids.append(proc_id)
```

The result of the print is:

```
print name = SO013

print val = {'origin': u'SO013'}
```

But the data is not inserted into the `procurement.order` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code me look like this after return statement is does not executes anything do put cdeo before return and your code need lot of tuning, like do not use SQL Injection it is not good idea.

```
def action_ship_create(self, cr, uid, ids, id_queue, context=None):
        queue_obj = self.pool.get('mo.queue'). browse (cr, uid, id_queue, context=context)
        queue_model = self.poo.get(queue_obj.name)
        procurement_pool = self.pool.get('procurement.order')
        qsids = queue_model.search(cr, uid, )
        for record in queue_model.browse(cr, uid, qsids):
          if record.origin:
               #this will crate a new record the table procurement.order so 
               #field values may be not enough so you can update logic
               #and If you want to update record value you need a proc ids and you can do it.
               procurement_pool.create(cr, uid, {'origin':record.origin})
        return {'value': {'origin': record.origin}}
```

Hope this will help you let me know i I am missing.

Thank You

Comment: that's only one field **origin**, how if much.. ? (origin,name,date_planned,etc) ?

Comment: @Dja: Simple in loop you can create a dict and then record.field_name you have vlaues. you can use them.